# Python: Merging Two Lists

Tags: python

I have two lists

```
    list1= [6, 1, 8, 1, 2]
   list2= ["Mail Opened", "Mail Not Opened", "Mail Opened", "Mail Not Opened", "Mail Not Opened"]
```

I was to trying results like

```
(14,"mailopened") (4,"mailnotopened")
```

First i tried to convert them Dict but it does not accept duplicate values.
is it Possible to add these lists according to the second list.

Comment: In Python, lists are denoted by square brackets `[]`. The parentheses are usually used with tuples.

Comment: my apologies , i have corrected my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `defaultdict` and simply add the values from `list1`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

list1 = [6, 1, 8, 1, 2]
list2 = ["Mail Opened", "Mail Not Opened", "Mail Opened", "Mail Not Opened", "Mail Not Opened"]

added = defaultdict(int)

for i, k in enumerate(list2):
    added[k] += list1[i]
```

This works because `defaultdict` supplies a default value if a key is accessed which doesn't exist. In this case, it will supply a default of `0` because we specified that it is an `int` type.

Use of `enumerate()` stolen from @GaretJax. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
dict_out = dict()
for list1_val, k in zip(list1, list2):
    dict_out[k] = dict_out.get(k, 0) + list1_val
```

Output:

```
In [10]: dict_out
Out[10]: {'not open': 4, 'open': 14}
```

Explanation:

1. `zip(list1, list2)` is equivalent to the sequence `(6, 'open'), (1, 'not open'), ..., (2, 'not open')`.
2. For dictionary `dict_out`, `dict_out.get(k, 0)` returns `dict_out[k]` if it exists, otherwise `0`.
3. Therefore, the `for` loop iterates over the five (value, key) pairs and accumulates them in the dictionary `dict_out`.

Comment: That is nice usage of `dict.get()` which I hadn't seen before. Thanks!

Comment: I tried it but it always give me AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Is it good way to use zip function? If list1 and list2 has different lenght.

Comment: Not for this question; I assume `list1` and `list2` have the same length. Nevertheless, `zip` does accept iterables of different lengths, but it just *truncates* each iterable to the shortest length. Example: `zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2])` returns `[('a', 1), ('b', 2)]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import defaultdict

list1 = [6, 1, 8, 1, 2]
list2 = ["Mail Opened", "Mail Not Opened", "Mail Opened", "Mail Not Opened", "Mail Not Opened"]

d = defaultdict(lambda:0)

for i, k in enumerate(list2):
    d[k]+=list1[i]

print d
print d.items()
```

Edit: voitos was faster with an identical solution (see above)

Comment: Hehe, nice. I noticed that you used a `lambda` instead of specifying `int`. Perhaps the `int` would have slightly better performance? Then again, `enumerate()` is probably faster than `zip()`, hah.

Comment: enumerate is surely more memory efficient too... ;-) didn't thought to use int at all... next time I will remember!

Comment: Btw @voithos, feel free to edit your answer to use `enumerate`; there is no reason that the next one with a similar problem uses `zip` ;-)